# Python Selenium Headless Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, webdriver, headless

I have this Python Selenium Threading script but how can I make it run headless ?

```js
def checkout(browser, url):
  browser.get(url)

browserThread1 = threading.Thread(target = checkout, args = (webdriver.Chrome(), 'https://www.google.com'))
browserThread2 = threading.Thread(target = checkout, args = (webdriver.Chrome(), 'https://www.google.com'))
browserThread3 = threading.Thread(target = checkout, args = (webdriver.Chrome(), 'https://www.google.com'))
browserThread4 = threading.Thread(target = checkout, args = (webdriver.Chrome(), 'https://www.google.com'))
browserThread1.start()
browserThread2.start()
browserThread3.start()
browserThread4.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create Chrome options and add it to thread which you want to run on headless mode.

```
import threading
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


def checkout(browser, url):
   browser.get(url)

options = Options()
options.headless = True

browserThread1 = threading.Thread(target = checkout, args = (webdriver.Chrome(options=options), 'https://www.google.com'))
browserThread2 = threading.Thread(target = checkout, args = (webdriver.Chrome(options=options), 'https://www.google.com'))
browserThread3 = threading.Thread(target = checkout, args = (webdriver.Chrome(options=options), 'https://www.google.com'))
browserThread4 = threading.Thread(target = checkout, args = (webdriver.Chrome(options=options), 'https://www.google.com'))
browserThread1.start()
browserThread2.start()
browserThread3.start()
browserThread4.start()
```